# dplyr not accepting paste0() as old_name in rename()

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to build a function that imports a bunch of csv files and cleans them. One of the cleaning functions involves pulling the year from the csv file name and pasting it to a column name, using dplyr rename(). For some reason it won't work. I am trying to work out why.

Here is a quick example:

```
df <- data.frame('value' = 1:5)
df
  value
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
```

When I try and rename, however:

```
rename(df, paste0('value', '_', gsub('([a-z]+_)|(\\.csv)', '', 'csv_2018.csv')) = 'value')
```

Throws:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "rename(df, paste0('value', '_', gsub('([a-z]+_)|(\\.csv)', '', 'csv_2018.csv')) ="
```

Notably this works fine:

```
paste0('value', '_', gsub('([a-z]+_)|(\\.csv)', '', 'csv_2018.csv'))
[1] "value_2018"
```

Also this works fine:

```
rename(df, 'value_2018' = 'value')
  value_2018
1          1
2          2
3          3
4          4
5          5
```

Problem seems to be with `paste0()` (rather than `gsub()` ) as this also does not work:

```
rename(df, paste0('value', '_') = 'value')
```

Throwing the same error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "rename(df, paste0('value', '_') ="
```

Obviously:`paste0('value', '_')` works to give: `"value_"`

I can solve this in other ways, but was wondering why dplyr would not accept paste0 as an input for `new_name`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expressions on the lhs of `=` will not work.  Instead use `:=` with `!!`

```
library(dplyr)
rename(df, !! paste0('value', '_', gsub('([a-z]+_)|(\\.csv)', '',
          'csv_2018.csv')) := 'value')
  value_2018
1          1
2          2
3          3
4          4
5          5
```

---

Or another option is `rename_with`

```
rename_with(df, ~ paste0('value', '_', gsub('([a-z]+_)|(\\.csv)', '',
           'csv_2018.csv')), 'value')
  value_2018
1          1
2          2
3          3
4          4
5          5
```